# Got "No threadId found for TeamId" error in List channels request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I tried to list channels in Teams with graph API. However, I got 404 NotFound error, and the error message is like "No team found with Group Id {group-id}". Here are my experiment steps:

Step 1: I list all teams in the organization with group API ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams)), and I get two teams. (team 1: b3c5debe-a291-4047-8f93-2b08a0c9114c, team 2: 4146fdc2-ff4c-4aa1-9ea9-a8c0bc85fc40) Both of them have "Team" tag in resourceProvisioningOptions field.

Step 2: I list all channels of team 1 (b3c5debe-a291-4047-8f93-2b08a0c9114c) ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) and it works fine.

Step 3: I tried to list channels of team 2 (4146fdc2-ff4c-4aa1-9ea9-a8c0bc85fc40) with same method in Step 2. But I got 404 NotFound error as mentioned above. More information:

- tenant_id: 292086d0-ea63-4e02-bc87-8366a95b6435
- application_id: 62f031e7-0380-4842-913a-06ba4ed36ed3
- request: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/4146fdc2-ff4c-4aa1-9ea9-a8c0bc85fc40/channels
- request-id: 6cb08d98-134a-4158-b85d-6ef831571772
- response status: 404 Not Found
- response body:

  ```
  {
      "error": {
          "code": "NotFound",
          "message": "No threadId found for TeamId 4146fdc2-ff4c-4aa1-9ea9-a8c0bc85fc40",
          "innerError": {
              "message": "No threadId found for TeamId 4146fdc2-ff4c-4aa1-9ea9-a8c0bc85fc40",
              "code": "Unknown",
              "innerError": {},
              "date": "2023-07-03T08:45:06",
              "request-id": "6cb08d98-134a-4158-b85d-6ef831571772",
              "client-request-id": "6cb08d98-134a-4158-b85d-6ef831571772"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I would be appreciate if someone can help me about it, thank you.

Comment: Could you please reverify if the team is in active state and hasn't been deleted/disabled?

Comment: Since I only have application credential, I tried to check with get team API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). 
I got 404 Not Found error, and the error message is "No team found with Group Id 4146fdc2-ff4c-4aa1-9ea9-a8c0bc85fc40". 
Therefore, I can't figure out the current status of this team.

Comment: Are you able to view this team in MS Teams? And did you check if the team id there matched the one you got from graph?

Comment: 1. No, I can't access to the Teams App directly. 
2. Yes, I checked the team id matched, as I mentioned in "Step 1". Should I provide the full API response?

Comment: We need to verify if that team really present in MS Teams or not. Without that it quite hard to figure out. Don't you have access to Ms Teams in that tenant?